# Drop-down auto selection disabling

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where I select a value in drop-down and submit it but when I try to access that form the value in the drop-down still remains selected, I want to deselect it on every new launch.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to set the value of the dropdown to what you want.

```
document.querySelector('#idOfDropdown').value = desired_value; 
// desired_value is the 'value' property of the option you want selected.
```

If the default option is written as

```
<option value=''>--select--</option>
```

...then, use this:

```
document.querySelector('#idOfDropdown').value = '';
```

I'm assuming that this line will be best placed at the end of the function that gets called when you submit the Form.

Comment: if you can see the image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4hWS.png) it is getting pre-selected to Accountant but I want it to be defaulted to --select--

Comment: @ChanShek Please share your HTML, or at least the `<select>` block

Comment: <td class="cpFieldCell"><div class="cpFieldWrapper"><select name="Override_LeadChannel" id="Override_LeadChannel" onchange="changeApplicantLeadChannelFields(true);">
<option value="-1">--select--</option>
<option value="844" selected="selected">Accountant</option>
<option value="861">Attorney</option>
<option value="862">Right Gives Back</option>
<option value="885">Builder/Sight Agent</option>
<option value="869">Business Review Website (Yelp)</option>
<option value="846">Car Dealership</option>
<option value="847">Carrier Referral</option>
</select></div></td>

Comment: You have `selected="selected"` on the "Accountant" option. Move that to the first option. Otherwise, to do it dynamically, use the expression in my asnwer but set the value equal to "-1".